# How to make exception in coding for safari visitors?

Tags: css, exception, css-animations

in a part of my code I have CSS3 animation and it seems does not work very well on safari, but it's fine on other browsers, so, I would like to make and exception, and if the browser is safari then it ignores the animation part of the code.
Here is my code:

```
download-music {
background: transparent url(../images/dl-music.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
float:left;
width:110px;
height:39px;
text-indent:-9999px;
opacity:0.5;
   -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
   -moz-opacity: 0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;   /* EXCEPTION FOR HERE */
   -o-transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;

}

.download-music:hover {-webkit-opacity:1 !important; -o-opacity:1; -moz-opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Selector hacks**

1.

```
/* Safari 2/3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child .selector {} 
html[xmlns*=""]:root .selector  {}
```

2.

```
/* Safari 6- and Chrome 24- */
::made-up-pseudo-element, .selector {}
```

3.

```
/* Safari 2/3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] .selector {}
```

**Media query hacks**

```
/* Safari 3+, Chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}
```

**JavaScript Hacks**

1.

```
/* Safari 5- */
var isSafari = /a/.__proto__=='//';
```

2.

```
/* Safari */
var isSafari = /Constructor/.test(window.HTMLElement);
```

Source: http://browserhacks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the prefixed `opacity`, it's been a couple of years since all browsers have supported it. It interferes with your transition declarations. This should work fine in all browsers.

```
.download-music {
  background: transparent url(../images/dl-music.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  float:left;
  width:110px;
  height:39px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  opacity:0.5;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  -moz-transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .45s ease-in-out;
}

.download-music:hover { 
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
}
```